# How to loop data from JSON to TH's and TD's in a Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, firebase, datatable

The th's of the Datatable are the keys/entities from the database and the td's are the values. The th's are not yet written on the html file because the web app will allow the admin to add more. I'm trying to append it but the sort button doesn't work. I use jquery and my database is Firebase

**Here is an example of my JSON.**

data = {IDNumber: "1", NAME: "Kim", A1: "10", A2: "20", A3: "30", …}
and
data = {IDNumber: "2", NAME: "Joon", A1: "9", A2: "19", A3: "29", …}

The table will look like this

**IDNumber | Name | A1 | A2 | A3 | ....**

1                 | Kim     | 10  | 20 | 30  | ....

2                 | Joon   | 9    | 19 | 29  | ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the documentation here https://datatables.net/

also you will have to have separate array of th's and td's to map

Comment: I can't seem so find the answer. I already looked at their docs and forums